# What is definition of independent random variable

Tags: correlation, random-process, independence, complex-random-variable

I wan't to ask that if

**E{X}=0**

**E{Y}=0**

and    **E{XY}=0**

then how can I verify if the two random variables are independent or not.

X , Y are both continuous random variables {I am not able to recall the exact equations for X , Y but  I am sure about the information given above and want some hint of how to proceed}.

What I know about independence {the definition that is causing confusion}

[image]

And so E{XY} should be = E{X}E{Y}

Which part of the below derivation doesn't sufficiently satisfies that X and Y are independent {where did it went wrong}

[image]

Transition from first line to second line is only possible if two random variables are independent and after it it's just rearrangement of terms.

Comment: independence means that $f(X | Y = y) = f(X)$ which just means that knowing the value of $Y$ doesn't provide any info about the density of $X$. In your notation, another way of saying it is that $E(X | Y = y) = E(X)$.

Comment: @mark leeds Can i use this notion combined with above information given above in question to get to some result that are X and Y independent.

Comment: @Buzzbee You don't have enough information to know if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @MBaz Thanks please see the edits

Comment: @Buzzbee That's correct, and that's why you don't have enough information. You don't know the marginal densities.

Comment: Hi: the joint is $f(X,Y) =  f(X | Y = y) * f(Y) $ so if $f(X| Y = y) = f(X)$, then $f(X,Y) = f(X) * f(Y)$ which is what you have with the P notation. But you have to know whether that's true.

Comment: hay Buzz, can you learn to use $\LaTeX$?  rather than pasting in images of equations?

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson yup busy for now may be in a month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, NO and** $\mathbf{NO}$.

Knowing that $E[X]=E[Y]=0$ and $E[XY]=0$ (or more generally that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ or equivalently, $E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]=0$) does not help in the least in *proving* or deducing that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.  The conditions stated in the previous sentence are *necessary* for $X$ and $Y$ to be deemed independent random variables, but they are a very far cry from being *sufficient* for independence to hold. That is, if $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$, then we might *suspect* that $X$ and $Y$ might be independent random variables, but we cannot *jump* to the conclusion that they *are* independent random variables based on just the evidence that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$.

> **Definition:** $X$ and $Y$ are said to be *independent* random variables (sometimes more prolixly *mutually independent* random variables) if their *joint* distribution function (joint CDF) $F_{X,Y}(u,v) = P\{X \leq u, Y\leq v\}$ satisfies
>   $$F_{X,Y}(u,v)=F_{X}(u)F_{Y}(v) ~\text{for all real numbers}~ u ~\text{and}~v.\tag{1}$$
>   Here, $F_{X}(u)=P\{X \leq u\}$ and $F_{Y}(v)=P\{Y\leq v\}$ are the *marginal* CDFs of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. It is important to remember the qualifier to the equality $F_{X,Y}(u,v)=F_{X}(u)F_{Y}(v)$: it must hold *at all points in the $u$-$v$ plane.*. Inanities such as "$X$ and $Y$ are independent when $X=5$ and $Y=3$ but not otherwise" are not permitted.

If $X$ and $Y$ are *discrete* random variables, then $(1)$ is equivalent to their joint _probability mass function (joint pmf) $p_{X,Y}(u_i, v_j)$ factoring into the product $p_X(u_i)p_Y(v_j)$ of the *marginal* pdfs
*for all $i$ and $j$*.

If $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* continuous random variables, then $(1)$ is equivalent to their joint _probability density function (joint pdf) $f_{X,Y}(u, v)$ factoring into the product $f_X(u)f_Y(v)$ of the *marginal* pdfs
_for all real numbers $u$ and $v$.

Now, as the OP correctly points out, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then it is true that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$, that is,
$$X, Y ~\text{independent random variables} \implies E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$$ but

> the *reverse* implication
>   $$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]\implies X, Y ~\text{independent random variables}$$
>   $$\mathbf{DOES~NOT~HOLD}$$

Still don't believe a word of all this malarkey? Consider discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that 
$$p_{X,Y}(1,0) = p_{X,Y}(-1,0) = p_{X,Y}(0,1) = p_{X,Y}(0,-1) = \frac 14.$$
Verify that

1. $X$ and $Y$ take on values $\pm 1$ with equal probability $\frac 14$ and value $0$ with probability $\frac 12$.
2. $XY=0$ always and so $E[XY]=0$ also, and that $E[X]=E[Y]=0$ also.
3. The joint pmf does not factor into the product of the marginal pdfs for at *any* of the four points where the joint pmf is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially $E\{XY\}=0$ (assuming $E\{X\}=E\{Y\}=0$) means that $X$ and $Y$ are [uncorrelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Correlation_and_independence), but **uncorrelated** is a weaker property than probabilistic **independence**.  A collection of independent random variables will always be uncorrelated, but being uncorrelated does not mean two random variables are independent.

Comment: Thanks please see the edits

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at things in the following perspective;

Statistical **independence** is an **assumption** imposed on events $A,B$ or random variables $X,Y$, whose (the assumption's) mathematical **consequence** is expressed as; 
$$ P( A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$$ and $$ E\{X Y\} = E\{X\}E\{Y\} $$

So these are the **consequences** of independence, but not the **cause** of it. (This is what Dilip Sarwate expresses in his answer).

There's a third consequence of (and is also a cause for) independence, regarding joint and marginal CDF/PDFs:

$$ F_{XY}(x,y) = F_X(x) F_Y(y) .$$  This will hold for **all** $x,y$ **only when** $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.

Furthermore, if this equality can be shown to hold for all $x,y$ (without assuming $X$  and $Y$ as independent) then from this we can also conclude that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Hence both a consequence of and a cause for it.

The above thing is mainly theoretical argumentation. In practice, from observed practical data, you can never fully and precisely check the third consequence and hence can never rigorously prove that random variables are indeed independent. This is not the preferred approach.

What you can practically do is to check (actually **estimate**) for the following to hold.

$$\sigma_{XY} = E\{ (X-\mu_Y)(Y-\mu_Y) \} = 0 $$ which implies that 
$$ E\{XY\} = E\{X\} E\{Y\} $$ and conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are **uncorrelated**.  (This is what RBJ expresses in his answer.) Note that when X and Y are assumed to be independent, then as a consequence, (by the last equation), they will also be uncorrelated; but the converse is not true as explained in the first part.

Again note that this is an estimation and is never perfectly accurate. Hence one can never be truly sure that RVs $X$ and $Y$ are indeed uncorrelated or be sure that whether the result of a normalized correlation being $0.001$ indicates an innacurate computation or just a **slight** correlation between $X$ and $Y$... What can only be said is that a slight correlation and truly uncorrelatedness will have the same (almost indistinguishable) effects on the result of DSP algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. WIll it be possible to predict is the signals are independent if it is given 1.they are ergodic 2.the value of signals with respect to time and random variable is given 3.but probability density of two signals is not mentioned .4.Also the necessary condition that E{XY}=E{X}E{Y} is followed (not given but as ensemble average is equal to time average so calculated) .If I can say that signals are independent or not if yes then how.

Comment: E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) is a necessary but not sufficient condition. A necessary and sufficient condition is F(x,y) = F(x)F(y) if you can verify the latter then you prove that X and Y are independent. But the former does not prove anything. However, the former can be used to **prove** the fact that X and Y are **dependent** i.e.; if $E(XY) \neq E(X)E(Y)$ then for sure you have proven that X and Y are **dependent** but when $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ it's not sufficient to argue that X and Y are indpendent. Summary, practically it's very hard to prove that signals are indeed independent.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[X]$ says that the two random variables are uncorrelated. Uncorrelated random variables are in general not independent, unless they are Gaussian random variables.

Comment: Thanks please see the edits

Comment: You proved that independent RVs are uncorrelated. But you want to prove that uncorrelated RVs are independent. This isn't the same.

Comment: But I fxy=fxfy is condition for independence isn't it.And I have used it for deriving whole thing then why its not suffecient.

Comment: You ASSUMED it, but didn't prove it from the uncorrelated RVs. Again, uncorrelated RVs doesn't imply independence, but independence implies uncorrelated RVs.

Comment: I assumed what isn't  f(X,Y)=f(X|Y=y)∗f(Y) so if f(X|Y=y)=f(X), then f(X,Y)=f(X)∗f(Y) condition for independence ?

Comment: Hi: there's no way, given X and Y, that you can prove that $f(X,Y) = f(X) *f(Y)$. This would have to be stated beforehand. For example, the problem might say "X and Y are independent and having the following marginal distributions". Fat 32's answer expresses nicely that, in practice,  independence is a fact or an assumption and not something that can be proven.

Comment: I just read your edited answer which I hadn't read before. Notice that when you go from the first integral to the second, you say "by independence". So, you aren't proving independence but rather assuming it.

Comment: @mark leeds Ya thanks got it .

Comment: @mark leeds WIll it be possible to predict is the signals are independent if it is given they are ergodic the value of signals with respect to time and random variable is given but probability density of two signals is not mentioned .Also the necessary condition that E{XY}=E{X}E{Y} is followed (not given but as ensembelled average is equal to time average so calculated) .If I can say that signals are independent or not if yes then how.

Comment: @Buzz bee. Technically and theoretically, no, its not possible. But, if you have two signals ( or random variables ) and you ( de-mean them first ) and  then estimate their cross correlation and you find that it's close to zero at all lags, then this is a practitioner's way of checking for independence. Technically, this isn't a perfect test because lack of correlation doesn't imply independence, except for normally distributed RV's. But, that's generally how it's tested for. A practitioner generally doesn't worry about lack of corr not implying independence.

Comment: One other thing: the procedure I describe above is only valid if the two variables ( signals ) are stationary. By this it is meant that the mean and variance ( of the two signals ) are not changing over time. This can be problematic in finance and econometrics. Maybe DSP too but I'm not sure.